# USB Barcode scanners Redirect order RDP on windows 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hardware, rdp, remote-desktop-services

I'm trying to get barcode scanners (usb, Motorola LS3578 is my test model) so re-direct over RDP, but i cant seem to get very far. The scanner works ok locally on the client, if i plug it into the 2008r2 server local it works, but i cant get it to re-direct over RDP.

I've installed the Remote-FX service on the terminal server, and enabled the 'Other RemoteFX Devices' option on the client, but i dont seem to get anywhere

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are attempting to do, nor what you mean by 'redirect'. Barcode scanners are keyboards, nothing more. There isn't anything to redirect. they should be plugged into the local PC which is connecting to the server. When you scan a barcode your local PC 'types' the sequence from the barcode into whichever application is open. That application can be the RDP client, but its just the same as typing.

Comment: Yeah i understand they act like keyboards, but its just not available in the users RDP session

Comment: Strange. I can confirm that this should work as we have plenty of clients with exactly this arrangement. Normally it just works. Are the scanners being plugged in afterwards? If so do you have "Supported Plug and Play Devices > Devices that I plug in later" marked? If its connected in a hub, try directly in the PC. MS do have a doc on the subject, but I'm not sure its much use: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-can-i-use-my-devices-and-resources-in-a-remote-desktop-session

Comment: The supported plug and play is active, the scanners are already connected to the client when it connects. I've built a test server and plugged the reader in directly and it see's it ok. I thought this was going to be a simple job